# How to pass string through command to new page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, command, parameter-passing

I'm facing the problem of sending string parameter as background image of my new page. What I want to achieve is like a list of object, every object has assing string of new background image, after clicking a icon of object user is redirect to new page with background image. The problem is that when sending parameter there is unhandled exception

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred

This is what I wrote to achieve this :

**MainPage xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="wasteListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Wastes}"
              HasUnevenRows="True" 
              Margin="10,20,5,150" 
              SeparatorVisibility="None"
              BackgroundColor="Transparent"
              ItemTapped="OnSelectedItem"
              >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                     BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                     ProgressColor="#614c96"
                                     Progress="{Binding ObjectCounter}"                                         
                                     />
                        <ImageButton x:Name="iconButton"
                                     Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                                     WidthRequest="100"
                                     HeightRequest="100"
                                     Aspect="AspectFit"
                                     BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                     Source="{Binding ObjcetIcon}"
                                     Command="{x:Binding Source={x:Reference wasteListView}, Path=BindingContext.NavigationCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="{x:Binding .}">

                        </ImageButton>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

MainPage code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var pageServices = new PageServices();
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel(pageServices);
    }

    private async void OnSelectedItem(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {   
        var sampleDetails= e.Item as SampleModel;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1(sampleDetails), true); 
    }
}
```

MainViewModel

```
    public ObjectModel sample;

    public MainViewModel(IPageServices pageServices)
    {
        this._pageServices = pageServices;

        Wastes = GetWastes();
        NavigationCommand= new Command(NavigateToObejctPage);
    }

    void NavigateToObjectPage(object obj)
    {
        _pageServices.PushAsync(new Page1(sample));
    }
```

Page services is my navigation service

Page1 codebehind:

```
    public Page1(SampleModel sampleModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //This is working when i tapped item from list view, 
        BackgroundImage = sampleModel.SampleBackgroundImage;
    }
```

Page1 xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AppDemo.Page1"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AppDemo.ViewModels"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
         BackgroundImage="{x:Binding sampleModel.SampleBackgroundImage}"
         >
</ContentPage>
```

What you see here working good and as expected but only on listview item tapped. How can i pass background image as parameter though command ? Thank you in advance for any ideas. If possible can I ask for some explanation? One more thank you :)

Comment: _pageServices.PushAsync(new Page1(sample)); - you never set a value for sample so it will always be null

Comment: sample object is created in Get westes() function , there are all object with values for Progress bar value  , Icon image  and  backgroundImage

Comment: Then I suggest you use the debugger to determine exactly which object is causing the null ref.